# Disable auto compilation of LESS

Tags: css, eclipse, maven, less

I am in Eclipse environment. I want LESS to compile only when explicitly invoked via mvn package. At the moment, as soon as I make any changes in my less file it propagates the change to CSS. What should I do to avoid this behaviour?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>
  <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0.1.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <watch>false</watch>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/css</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/css</outputDirectory>
    <compress>true</compress>
    <force>true</force>
    </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>package</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

also posted this issue [here](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin/issues/71)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define in which [maven phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) you want to execute your plugin, basically adding the `phase` tag under the `execution` tag. Take look to the following examples: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag.

Comment: I already tried '<phase>package</phase>' and many others but didn't work. Do you know specifically which tag might work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I have encapsulated LESS plugin inside a profile. On server side I invoke that profile to do LESS compilation

```
mvn package -pless_compile
```

Answer (score 0):

[M2Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) is an Eclipse plugin which provides tight integration for Maven. It determines who and when plugins should be executed. Each plugin can store lifecycle mapping metadata with data on which it based its decision (see [M2E compatible maven plugins](https://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_compatible_maven_plugins#Overview)). By default this plugin is called on incremental builds:

```
<lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    <pluginExecutions>
        <pluginExecution>
            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </pluginExecutionFilter>
            <action>
                <execute>
                    <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                    <runOnConfiguration>false</runOnConfiguration>
                </execute>
            </action>
        </pluginExecution>
    </pluginExecutions>
</lifecycleMappingMetadata>
```

If you want to disable automatic compilation, then you need to add the following entry to your `pom.xml`:

```
<pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
         <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
               <pluginExecutions>
                  <pluginExecution>
                     <pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <versionRange>[0,)</versionRange>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                     </pluginExecutionFilter>
                     <action>
                        <ignore />
                     </action>
                  </pluginExecution>
               </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```