# How to compile LESS into CSS when files are saved in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, web-applications, ant, less

I'm developing a `struts2 webapp` for months now using maven to manage my dependencies and I've just discovered `LESS`. I have installed and configured the `LESS plug-in for Eclipse` but it's really annoying to `right click > run as > LESS compiler` every time I save the .less file due to a modification of its content or something...
 The thing is that I've been researching on how to plug in `grunt.js` (recently discovered task runners too) into maven ([as explained here](http://addyosmani.com/blog/making-maven-grunt/)) but I think it's quite hard and I wondered if somebody knew an alternative to this.

In my `struts2` project I have both the front and back-end of my webapp.I know it's not the right approach and if I could start all over again I would separate them into two different projects, but now it's too late (disadvantages of the learning proccess, we're not born knowing it all).

Having said all this, how can I set up a kind of task for watching my `.less` files and automatically compile them into `.css` when saved/changed?

I also found [this ant task here](https://github.com/chubbard/WatchTask), but I dont really know if it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of Java Less compiler (see [Java Compiler for Less CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9739724/4944847)), so you can execute one of them by your build tool (e.g. [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) - maybe you need to write a simple Java application, which use the chosen compiler).

If you use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) (or can switch to it) to project management, then you can use one of lesscss-maven-plugin:

- [biz.gabrys.maven.plugins:lesscss-maven-plugin](http://lesscss-maven-plugin.projects.gabrys.biz/)
- [org.lesscss:lesscss-maven-plugin](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin)
- [see more...](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22lesscss-maven-plugin%22)

Comment: I'm going to try some of the maven plugins and see if that indeed works for me. If it does work, I'll accept this answer. Many thanks

Comment: If a maven plugin is used, when would it compile the less plugins? every time I save changes on them? or every time I export/deploy my webapp on the server

Comment: Depending on the plugin configuration. It can compile after every save or during project building (see: [Disable auto compilation of LESS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827640/disable-auto-compilation-of-less)). If you use `biz.gabrys.maven.plugins:lesscss-maven-plugin` then it compile after file save.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as I found it usefull. I'll look into maven plugin configuration and see if I can learn how to configure it. Many thanks @agabrys

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create an `ant` task to compile certain `.less` files into `CSS` whenever they are modified, and more or less is what I was looking for, but `grunt` seems to be more flexible as you can tell it to **watch** all your files with `.less` extension and in this solution I've found you have to declare in an `.xml` file the `.less` files you want `ant` to watch.

This is not explicitly what I was looking for so I'll leave this question open for now as I'll keep researching on how to make this solution more dynamic and see if it is possible to avoid the fact of defining every `.less` source and `.css` target you want.

[Link to solution here](http://www.mihaitha.net/2014/eclipse-compile-less-to-css/)

Comment: The page you linked to is gone... Here it is in the wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20160115133504/http://www.mihaitha.net/2014/eclipse-compile-less-to-css